# Role permissions on other users

Tags: 7, users

I'm working on my drupal website.

I need that Manager(a custom user role) and Publisher(a custom use role) can upload documents (a custom content type) and until here it's all ok.

Then i need also that for example there is:

user A that is a manager

user B is a publisher

user C is publisher

I want assign the possibility for A to see the documents uploaded by B, but not C documents.

How i can do it ?

Thank You.

Comment: You can not do it. Because you have a publisher role, B and C both have a same publisher role. In this case A will be able to see both B and C documents (of course if A has a permission to see publisher's documents).

Comment: But there aren't some plugins ? maybe something like groups...i don't know :S